# Does attempted murder carry the same punishment as successful murder in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

For example, let's say you use the Killing Curse (Avada Kedavra), which is one of the three Unforgivable Curses on a human being, but it misses, like what Dumbledore did with Voldemort with the statues by animating them to take the shot. Would you get charged with the same crime as though you actually killed the intended target despite not killing the intended target?

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be "murder"... but one might be accused of being "dark" for the attempt, and who knows what penalties were applied for that handwavingly fuzzy charge.  I don't think there was a lot of standardization when it comes to magical law... or law, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

No.

1. Merely wishing to use the curse isn't punuishable. Lucius Malfoy tried to use AK on Harry Potter after he tricked Lucius to free Dobby with a sock at the end of *CS*; yet suffered no repercussions.
2. Firing off AK by itself isn't punishable. Witness fake Mad-Eye (Barty) using it on a spider during a lesson in GoF.

As such, it's likely it's not "same" punishment.

Comment: For 1, that might just be because Lucius is rich and powerful, and/or because Harry didn't press charges. In fact, same could go for #2, kids aren't known to snitch, especially on a guy who uses Unforgivable Curses in class.

Comment: Malfoy didn't try to use AK in that instance. He "lunged" at Harry, which is hardly the same as AK.